# How to play a HTML5 video with cordova on an Android device

Tags: html, cordova

I want to play a video on my application for Android and I want to use HTML5.

I have a video called: video.mp4 and it is in my raw folder
path: `"C:\android\workspace\Project\platforms\android\res\raw\video.mp4"`

and I have this code:

```
<video class="responsive" width="100%" height="545px" controls>
  <source src="C:\android\workspace\Project\platforms\android\res\raw\video">
</video>
```

But it can't find my video file. Am I doing something wrong, or isn't this possible.
I'm creating this app in cordova 3.x.x